# How to build model from column index instead of name (see inside)?

Tags: r

Let's say I have this sample data:

```
|Month|Spend|Sales|
|-----|-----|-----|
|1----|1000-|9914-|
|2----|4000-|40487|
|3----|5000-|54324|
```

If I want to build a model I would do something like this:

```
dataset = read.csv("data-marketing-budget-12mo.csv", header=T)
simple.fit = lm(Sales~Spend, data=dataset)
summary(simple.fit)
```

but I want to be able to do it like this:

```
dataset = read.csv("data-marketing-budget-12mo.csv", header=T)
simple.fit = lm(dataset[3]~dataset[2], data=dataset)
summary(simple.fit)
```

Comment: Try using `which` or `match`.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract a vector from a dataframe using `[[`. Then you would be able to remove the `data = dataset` like so:

```
dataset = read.csv("data-marketing-budget-12mo.csv", header=T)
simple.fit = lm(dataset[[3]] ~ dataset[[2]])
summary(simple.fit)
```